# Plot on the same twin scale

Tags: matplotlib, plot, subplot

I would like to plot three set of data, one with one y ax and the other two with another ax. As now I write the code as:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(a)
ax2.plot(b, "r")
ax3.plot(c, "y")
plt.show()
```

In this way, on the right side of the picture I have two different scales. How can I have only one? How can I make so that "a" data are plotted on the left y ax and "b" and "c" data are plotted on the right side? (with the exact same scale)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ax3` from the code. It has no purpose. Then call `ax2.plot(c, "y")` to show the `c` data on `ax2`, just as you did with the data `b`.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(a)
ax2.plot(b, "r")
ax2.plot(c, "y")
plt.show()
```